# SQL Replication - Data not showing

Tags: sql-server, replication

Good Morning,

I have recently setup SQL replication and changed some data in one of the tables on the primary table. This data however has not been replicated to the subscription server.

On the subscription server synchronization is in progress all the time.

This is my first attempt at setting up replication so I apologize in advance.

Any questions or more info needed just ask.

Comment: Have you pulled open Replication Monitor to see what is happening, or if there are any errors with any agents/etc.?

Comment: Did you even run the snapshot agent after setting up replication ? And when you initially set up replication, were the subscriber having data. ?

Comment: What type of replication u setup merge or transactional ?